# Why is this for loop logging correctly, but write to sheet wrongly using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm running this for loop and modifying some values on the go. It logs the values changed correctly in each iteration, but it repeats the last iteration when writing to sheets.

```
const rngList = cadSheet.getRangeList(dataRng).getRanges();

  //Gets the ranges' values and push them into an array;
  let values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rngList.length; i++) {
    values = [].concat(values, rngList[i].getValues().flat());
    //values.push([rngList[i].getValue()]);
  }

  let itens = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < tamanhosEscArr.length; a++) {
    for (let r = 0; r < coresEscArr.length; r++) {
      values[4] = variacao++;//Increments an ID number
      values.splice(29, 1); //removes this element
      values.splice(29, 0, tamanhosEscArr[a]); //inserts size being iterated over

      values.splice(30, 1);//removes this element
      values.splice(30, 0, coresEscArr[r]); //inserts color being iterated over

      Logger.log('Item: ' + values) //logs all 18 or so items, with their corresponding sizes and colors
      itens.push(values);
    }
  }
  suporteSheet.getRange(suporteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, itens.length, itens[0].length).setValues(itens); //Writes the last iteration as many times as the iterations (18)
```

This is the log, showing the correct result:
[image]

This is how this is writing to the spreadsheet:
[image]

I can't see where the flaw is here, besides my existence.

Thanks for the light!

Comment: Need [mcve]. Where is `values` defined?

Comment: Just added it, @TheMaster. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: It would be much easier if you show your input data and desired outcome. Since the code looks pretty bizarre.

Comment: Yes, @YuriKhristich! This will generate an item N times, as per size and colors being iterated. The weird part is actually logging it correctly, each iteration with its size and color, but writing only the last iteration result 18 times repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
itens.push(values);
```

to:

```
itens.push(values.slice());
```

**Еxplanation**

Log shows you the current state of the array `values` at every iteration of the loop. During the next iteration, you change the array `values`. And all 'previous instances' of the array are changing as well. This is why you're getting the 18 identical arrays. Because all of them are 'references' to the same array `values`.

If you want to prevent the changes in the 'previous instances' you have to make a copy of current state of the array `values` and put in the `itens` this copy. The method `array.slice()` returns a copy of a given array.

Comment: Right on! But why would this log correctly, then and would you mind sharing why ```slice()``` in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I've added an explanation into my answer.

Comment: Thanks a million! This, I won't find/learn in the "books" easily.